# Find a power series representation for $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{3+6x^3}$, and also for $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

> Find power series representations, centered at $x=0$, for $f(x)$ and the derivative of $f(x)$, where
> $$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{3+6x^3}$$

I am struggling with this question and need help on the steps in order to transition it to a power series.

I believe it will roughly follow the form of $\dfrac 1{1-x}$, but am getting confused. Any help is welcome as I am lost with both the original function and the power series of the derivative
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{6x\left(1-x^3\right)}{\left(3+6x^3\right)^2}$$

Comment: Hey! Welcome to math stackexchange, please use mathjax to format your questions in the future (I've edited it for you already).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Rewrite as

$$\frac{x^2}3\frac1{1+2x^3}$$ and set $z:=2x^3$.

Comment: do you need to simplify further than x^2/3 (-2x)^3n?

Comment: @Mel: put it in the standard power series form.